# Does Sublime Text 3 keep a command log? If so, where can I find it?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I use Sublime Text 3 and can open Sublime command line with command <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

... and I can run commands there and see results in a log window, but I cannot search in that log window.

[image: sublime command line and log]

I believe the log text of the Sublime log window also exists somewhere in file system.  If I can find that log file, I can open it with `vim` (or similar) and search there.

My question: Where is the log file stored?  I can copy/paste this log to new file and search there, but that would be a frustrating extra step.

My OS is OS X 10.8.5

I searched `/Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3` but nothing found.

This is my directory output.

```
Makss-Mac:Sublime Text 3 maks$ ls
Cache           Installed Packages  Packages
Index           Local
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, use this: [yrammos / SublimeLog](https://github.com/yrammos/SublimeLog)

From README

> Sublime Text 2 and 3 provide a console (accessible via Control-`) for interaction with their Python-based innards and plug-in architecture. This plug-in logs the console contents into a plain-text file ornamented with logger activation/deactivation timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.

You can see console history this file:

```
/Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Data/Local/Session.sublime_session
```

It is a JSON file and the console commands are stored in `windows.console.history`.

One note though, Sublime Text does not update the file until you close the program.

Comment: for me path was `/Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session`. Due to it is updated only after closing sublime, it is not compatible for my task. thank you anyway.